# Xamarin Top/Titlebar keeps re-appearing [iOS]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TabbedPage within a MasterDetailPage and want to disable/hide the top/titlebar. But every time I reboot the app the title bar re-appears and only goes away after I have navigated between tabs. I've tried disabling in code and disabling in XAML but it always shows the navigation bar when the app loads. It only disappears after I've navigated between two tabs.

I've used `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in the `OnAppearing` function, the constructor, I'm using `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"`.

I also have a custom TabbedPage and the background color of the current tab is also glitched out whenever you start the app. But after the navigation is used it goes to the right size. Please see the screenshots below:

When starting the app:
[image]

After navigating between tabs:

[image]

Does someone know if I am missing something important?

Comment: May be while navigating first time, you are using mainpage= new navigationpage(new yourpage()); please remove new navigation page while navigating.

Comment: I'm not using NavigationPage, The MaterDetailPage is called like this:

`MainPage = new MasterDetailPage()`

Comment: Have you tried by creating master detail page renderer and set padding to 0, as mentioned here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/185322/#Comment_185322

Comment: also you can check how you have set your detail page, as mentioned here, remove new navigation page from there: http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/november/xamarin-masterdetailpage-has-large-marginpadding-at-top/

Comment: Show us your code then we can help you better. I think there are two navigationBar in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

I removed all children in the TabbedPage XAML file and added them programmatically.

I had them like this (according to Xamarin [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#creating-a-tabbedpage)):

```
<NavigationPage Title="List" Icon="List" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
        <x:Arguments NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
            <page:ReservationListPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Map" Icon="Map">
        <x:Arguments>
            <page:MapPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

etc..
```

I removed them and added this to my CS file:

```
this.Children.Add(new ReservationListPage()
            {
                Title = "List",
                IconImageSource = "List"
            });

            this.Children.Add(new MapPage()
            {
                Title = "Map",
                IconImageSource = "Map"
            });
```